# How to get video player to NOT auto play while using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, xcode4.3

I'm trying to code a video into my iPhone app and the code below works perfectly but the only thing is that I rather the video not automatically start playing when the user opens the page.  I want them to be able to push the play button.  The code below is located in my viewcontroller.m file.

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"77860_00_01_MM02_welcome" 
ofType:@"mov"];
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:player];

player.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 235, 150, 125);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];

[player play];
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [aNotification object];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 removeObserver:self
 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayer];
[moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
[player play];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Never mind, I figured it out. I just added `[player prepareToPlay]` under `player.shouldAutoplay = NO`

Answer (score 0):

Don't put it in your viewDidLoad. Just create an IBAction them link it up to your trigger button.