# MPMoviePlayerController plays without -play being called after -prepareToPlay is called

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have some code that sets up an MPMoviePlayerController to play back a video stored in the app.

I follow the example code in Apple's documentation.  However, the video plays even if I don't call -play on it as long as I have called -prepareToPlay.

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_videoName ofType:@"mp4"]];

MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

[player setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];

[player setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];

[[player view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
[[self view] addSubview:[player view]];


[player prepareToPlay];

//[player play];
```

Will play the video.  I uncomment the -play and the same thing happens.  It does not matter if I have -play in or not.  And I had -prepareToPlay earlier in the code as well (before the view setup) and it did not  make a difference.

This is on iOS8 of some sort.    I have not tried other versions of iOS.

Why does it work like this?  The Apple docs make it sound like it should not play until -play is called.

Comment: Are you sure you are not calling play method anywhere else, because this method will not start play, Even play method call this to prepare it if its not already called.

Comment: Check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563840/how-to-get-video-player-to-not-auto-play-while-using-mpmovieplayercontroller)

Comment: Whoever down voted should explain why they down voted it.  I searched for similar questions, and as I did not realize the magic word is "autoplay" did not find similar questions.

Comment: Sorry to all the idiots who are down voting, but get a life.  I searched before hand and did not find the linked answer.  And the SO auto suggest did not suggest it.   Down voting is just mental masturbation on your part.  Putting in a handy -- check here link -- and marking as a duplicate is sufficient.  Down voting when someone made the effort to check, but did not have the magic keyword(s) necessary to find the existing question just turns people off to SO and the ego trips people get on when policing others questions.  Especially when you are not willing to put your name to the down vote.

Comment: I agree with you, policing is the biggest issue on stack people are more than happy to down vote instead of helping others or just provide a similar question link and mark it duplicate without actually going through entire post  and trying to figure out the actual problem in many cases question looks similar but it could be entirely different problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this line of code

```
player.shouldAutoplay = NO;
```

By default it is set to YES.